# Magento download links have spaces

Tags: magento-1.9, download-link

I have many download-links which contain spaces in the folders and file-names.
Because of that they do not work in magento.

Does anybody know a workaround to maken them work somehow?

Thanks,
Marcel

Comment: Not clear, Can you please explain little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue: Magento cannot deal with downloadfiles that have spaces. They should all be replaced by - or _.
No other way to do it!